# Detecting client ctrl-c sockets

Tags: c, sockets, server, signals, copy-paste

I'm trying to detect when a client for my socket has disconnected using ctrl-c, and then ignore it.

I know of **signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)** but when I put that in my server side, it just creates the ignore-ctrl-c on the server side, which is not what I want.

How can I apply this behavior to just the client, so the server will continue after the client quits out?
I don't control the client's code.

Comment: Client's don't disconnect using Ctrl-C. The OS will send a SIGINT to the process when a local user presses Ctrl-C... I'd love to answer your actual question, but I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: Do you mean SIGPIPE?

Comment: talk is cheat; show us the code.

Comment: to clarify, if the client quits unexpectedly, I would like to ignore that and proceed

Comment: Apologies if I misused terms

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to detect a Ctrl-C on the client since no such information are transferred through the socket - unless your client application specifically is designed to transmit such information. But unless you specifically handle Ctrl-C in your client it will just exit which will cause the socket to be closed. Such socket close can be detected by reading on the socket: it will return no data and no error as a sign that the socket is closed. What you will not detect this way is the reason for the socket close, i.e. you don't know if it was caused by an explicit Ctrl-C, because the client crashed, or if the client has just closed the socket but it still running.

Comment: More accurately, a read operation will report 0 bytes received with no error code ONLY IF the connection was closed *gracefully* (the client sends a TCP `FIN` packet). Otherwise, the read operation will fail (eventually, after a timeout) with an error code if the connection is lost *abnormally*.